# Extend a direct instance

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

We have a new instance of an object with four properties:

```
person={firstname:"John",lastname:"Doe",age:50,eyecolor:"blue"};
```

What is the best way to **many** other properties to that object?
If we wanted few couple more sure we would:

```
person[address_no] = 4;
....
person[country] = 'Netherlands';
```

But what if we have a lot properties. Is there any minimalistic way like the one below? (I know it doesn't work)

```
person +={address_no: '4', .... , country: 'Netherlands'};
```

Comment: Check out the implementation of the [jQuery `extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) function in the source code of jQuery.

Comment: @Sniffer Thanks, that was the cleanest way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sperate JSON object and then merge it in first object

Use this function

```
function extend(a, b){
    for(var key in b)
        if(b.hasOwnProperty(key))
            a[key] = b[key];
    return a;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/w8yC4/)